# SQL - find the closest pair of numbers to a provided pair

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a DB Table where I would like to select the entry which is the closest match to a pair of provided values, whether positive or negative.

Provided values:

```
 num1 = 2.5, num2 = 10.2
```

Compared to:

```
[0] num1 = 1.1, num2 = 11.0
[1] num1 = 2.5, num2 = 14.1
[2] num1 = 2.4, num2 = 10.5
[3] num1 = 3.2, num2 = 10.3
```

The query I am looking for would return row [2]. Event though there are a couple closer values, the closest pair would be [2].

I would like to handle this in an SQL select statement. Here is what I have but it is not quite getting there in comparing both pairs of numbers.

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE num1 < 2.5 ORDER BY num1 DESC LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE num1 >= 2.5 ORDER BY num1 LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE num2 < 10.2 ORDER BY num2 DESC LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE num2 >= 10.2 ORDER BY num2 LIMIT 1)
```

This is giving me 4 close matches, but not the single closest match. I am sure my syntax is missing something, but I am not finding the trick to returning the single, closest match.

All ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to sort the table by the aggregate (or whatever metric you prefer) absolute distance between the target and the records:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY ABS(2.5-num1) + ABS(10.2-num2)
LIMIT    1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26be6/1/0).

Comment: I am using this to build a "nearest location" type function by comparing a geocoded Long Lat with a Long Lat stored in my DB. With this in mind I expanded on @eggyal solution to make the order by a little more accurate based on point on a map.
---
`ORDER BY sqrt(pow(40.4298410-latitude,2)*pow(-105.1041089-longitude,2))`

Comment: @august: There's not much point in taking the `sqrt()`, as the order will be unchanged. You should also be aware that the surface of a sphere is not a Euclidean geometry, so Pythagoras' theorem does not hold: you cannot apply it to lat/long this manner to obtain distance. You should instead use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula): there is a good tutorial in the [Finding Locations with MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql) section of Google Developers article "Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps".