# SQLite : Select row with closest value but limit the difference between passed value and closest value

Tags: android, sqlite

Suppose I have a table containing two columns as follows

```
  Size  |  Time  |
------------------
  215   |  24868 |
------------------
  105   |  25668 |
------------------
  515   |  64848 |
------------------
  321   |  44808 |
```

I need to select the `Time` having the `Size` closest to the passed value say `X`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19643777/2035645) I have the following query (`X= 800`)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY ABS(800-Size) LIMIT 1
```

This query gives me row with size 515, but I need to limit the difference between `X` and the selected value. 
For example: if I pass 800 then it should return only if the size is between 750 to 850, otherwise the query should not return anything.

Comment: Maybe map the difference into a computed column, sort by it and add a where clause that filters "too far" values on that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where Size >= (800-val) and Size <= (800+val) ORDER BY ABS(800-Size) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where size > (800-size) and size < (800+size)
```

Try this one.  Let me know it works or not.

Comment: that will give me all values between the range but I also want the closest in that range.

Comment: In following values which one is closest for 500. 501, 499, 515

Comment: 501 or 499, doesn't matter the time will be almost same. I also posted a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Welcome.  @shantanu